# How to check the status each 10 seconds with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a server (*mysite.com/status*), which returns number of active tasks (just a single integer).
How can I check number of active tasks each 10 seconds with JavaScript and show user something like:

> Number of remaining tasks: XXX

And, if number of tasks is 0, then I should load another page.

Comment: You have to use AJAX - can you get hold of jQuery? If so, it's one line solution and cross browser, otherwise it's big headache, but still possible.

Comment: I don't use jQuery. Can it be XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Yes but making it cross browser will be headache. I have old code somewhere, untested for long time - want me to post it anyway?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, If I would agree to reload the page each 10 secs, will it be much more easy?

Comment: I don't think it's relevant - you still need to grab the data from different page, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a function set a new timeout calling itself.

```
function checkTasks(){
    // Make AJAX request
    setTimeout(checkTasks, 10000);
}
checkTasks(); // Start task checking
```

Comment: Is it not easier to use `setInterval(function(){ // Make AJAX request },10000);`

Comment: @Billy Moon: see http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/05/14/setinterval-is-moderately-evil.aspx

Answer (score 3):

with jQuery for AJAX functions... (untested code)

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.get('http://example.com/status',function(d){
    // where there is html element with id 'status' to contain message
    $('#status').text('Number of remaining tasks: '+d)
    if(d == 0){
      window.location = '/another/page'
    }
  })
},10000)
```

Comment: may be because u didnt see that he said he has a function that returns `status`. i have edited ur code. maybe this time its correct

Comment: I would lovesh to see that - but where do I find the edited code?

Comment: @lovesh don't edit other people answers with your own ideas. It's rude. Instead say what you have to say in comments. for the record, I rejected [your suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/86792).

Answer (score 0):

```
 setInterval(function(elem){     // here elem is the element node where you want to display the message
        var status=checkStatus();  // supposing that the function which returns status is called checkStatus
        if(status == 0){
          window.location = '/another/page'
        }
        else {
         elem.innerHTML="Number of remaining tasks:"+status;
        }
    },10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have thought of different approach, without any AJAX. As you just need to show simple plain data, just use `<iframe>` to show that dynamic data then with simple JS "reload" the frame every 10 seconds.

HTML would be:

```html
Number of remaining tasks: <iframe id="myFrame" src="mysite.com/status"></iframe>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.setTimeout(ReloadTime, 10000);
};

function ReloadTime() {
    var oFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
    oFrame.src = oFrame.src;
    window.setTimeout(ReloadTime, 10000);
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/tmFaN/), using time for the same of example.

With some CSS you can make the frame look like part of the text, just set fixed width and height and remove the borders.

Answer (score -3):

Using the javascript library jquery, you can set a repeating infinite loop.
That gets the data from a page and then sets the inner html of an element.

http://jsfiddle.net/cY6wX/14/
This code is untested

edit: demonstration updated
Also I did not use the jquery selector for setting the value in case you do not want to use jquery.

Comment: You can also set "infinite loop" with pure JavaScript, simple matter of `window.setInterval()` - you also didn't post any code.

Comment: It appears I copied the url before saving, I will re-write the example momentarily.

Comment: -1 `setInterval("updateStatus()", 10000);` forcing an `eval()` is a horrible solution.

Comment: So you chose NOT to use JQuery for setting the value, but you chose TO use it for `$.get()` and then didn't even include the JQuery framework from the menu on the left?